# Retrieving system date and time?

Tags: android, textview

As a starter project (I'm new to programming), I wanted to make a simple app that would show four TextViews: The current time (Hours and minutes), the day, the date of the month, and the year. It seemed relatively simple and I researched and the code below is what I came up with. Would anyone be able to explain why my app force closes? I didn't see anything in the available permissions list that said anything about reading the system time. Thanks in advance. (NOTE: This is the only class and layout that I'm using.)

MainActivity.java:

```
package press.linx.calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView day = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.day);
    TextView month = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.month);
    TextView year = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.year);
    TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Time);


    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();

    day.setText(today.monthDay);             // Day of the month (0-31)
    month.setText(today.month);              // Month (0-11)
    year.setText(today.year);                // Year 
    time.setText(today.format("%k:%M:%S"));  // Current time
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="89dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/day"
    android:layout_marginRight="74dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/month"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/day"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Time"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/month"
    android:layout_below="@+id/month"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: please show your logcat error log.

Comment: use Date d=new Date(); and get hours as d.getHours();

Comment: i dnt under stand your logic at 
 TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Time);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your error.

`today.monthDay` gives an integer value, and when you set this in a `TextView` it searches for a resource with that `id`. You must be getting a `Resources$NotFoundException`.

Try this:

```
day.setText("" + today.monthDay);             // Day of the month (0-31)
month.setText("" + today.month);              // Month (0-11)
year.setText("" + today.year);                // Year 
time.setText("" + today.format("%k:%M:%S"));  // Current time
```

Comment: This fixed it perfectly. If I wanted it to poll for the time in certain intervals, so it'll update (now it only shows the time the app was opened), how should I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: U can do this by using `CountDownTimer` and in `onFinish()` method update your `Views`. Heres a link for how to use `CountDownTimer` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java util and SimpleDateFormat and Date for the same purpose:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

// Day of the month (0-31)
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
String day = sdf.format(new Date(time));
day.setText(day);

// month
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M");
String month = sdf.format(new Date(time));
month.setText(month);

// year
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("y");
String year = sdf.format(new Date(time));
year.setText(year);

// time
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm:ss a");
String time = sdf.format(new Date(time));
time.setText(time);
```

All the time string formats can be found at [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score -1):

Use this java utils method to retrieve the system current date and time.

```
Time dtNow = new Time();
dtNow.setToNow();
String sytem_time_date = dtNow.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); //use single text view to show
```